# Oracle minus operation how to escape parentheses in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which is called TableA. It contains 4 columns which are id,name,country,amount.The other TableB contains 4 columns which are id,name,country,amount.

TablaA contains some data like that

```
14|Jone|England|700
14|Steve|Hungary|400
15|Alex|Germany(munich)|500
12|Gerrard|Ireland|400
```

TableB contains some data like that

```
14|Jone|England|500
14|Steve|Hungary|400
15|Alex|Germany(dortmund)|500
```

When I execute this query , `select * from TablaA minus select * from TableB` I get these results

```
14|Jone|England|700
15|Alex|Germany(munich)|500
12|Gerrard|Ireland|400
```

But I am expecting these result

```
14|Jone|England|200
12|Gerrard|Ireland|400
```

How to escape paranthesis data ?

Comment: I want `id,name,county,amount`.Yes I want to strip out city.Resultant amount should be difference.If amount is 0, I want to show it if they are different rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```
SELECT
  TableA.id,
  TableA.name,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(TableA.country, '\(.*\)', ''),
  TableA.amount - COALESCE(TableB.amount, 0)
FROM
  TableA
LEFT JOIN
  TableB
    ON  TableA.id = TableB.id
    AND TableA.name = TableB.name
    AND REGEXP_REPLACE(TableA.country, '\(.*\)', '')
        =
        REGEXP_REPLACE(TableB.country, '\(.*\)', '')
WHERE
  TableA.amount - COALESCE(TableB.amount, 0) != 0
```

The `REGEXP_REPLACE()` replaces everything from the first `(` to the last `)` with an empty string *(so removes the `(city)` part, but may misbehave if `()` appear for other reasons)*.

You may also get undesired behavior if the same name appears in one table twice or more, with different `(city)` parts in their country.  If you need to cope with that, you need to demonstrate the behaviour you're dealing with, and how you want to handle it, in the example data in your question.

If this isn't what you need, please edit you question to show more examples and an explanation of why certain rows do / don't appear, and how you arrive at the values present, etc.

Comment: @tom - You should probably also change my `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to the `REXEXP_SUBSTR()` from the other answer here.  Instead of replacing `(*)` with an emptry string, it just returns everything up to the first `(`, if one is present.  It feels a little bit more robust to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want `id`/`name`/`amount` combinations that are in only one table.  If that is correct:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id and b.name = a.name and b.amount = a.amount)
union all
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id and b.name = a.name and b.amount = a.amount);
```

Comment: My reading is that they want `'Germany(munich)'` and `'Germany(dortmund)'`  to both be treated as `'Germany'`?

Comment: Yeah.Also amount difference